# Android App crashed in Lollipop while using Movie class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Android App crashed in Lollipop but working in marshmallow and Nougat while using Movie class. When we try to draw the image at the below line the app crashes, we are not getting any exception.

this.movie.Draw(canvas, 0, 0, p);

But when i tried to draw the image from a movie to a different canvas then it works fine but after some time i get Out of Memory exception.

//CODE

Bitmap movieBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(movie.Width(), movie.Height(), Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

Canvas movieCanvas = new Canvas();

movie.Draw(movieCanvas, 0, 0, p);

Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, movie.Width(), movie.Height());

canvas.DrawBitmap(movieBitmap, src, src, p);

I am using Xamarin Android for development. Why this issue occurs any suggestions.

Comment: To avoid the OutOfmemory problem Dispose the bitmap after rendering it on the canvas.

Comment: Still i am getting the same issue - OOM exception

Comment: Try to do a GC.Collect each 20/50 images, but that can kill the performance.